# JPA JPQL: select items when attribute of item (list/set) contains another item

Tags: list, jpa, set, jpql

```
public class Document extends Model {
... 
@ManyToMany
public Set<User> accessors;
...
}
```

I want to select all Documents which accessors contain a certain user.
I have just minimal experiences with SQL and no experiences with JPQL.
So how to do that?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 66):

```
SELECT d FROM Document AS d WHERE :user MEMBER OF d.accessors
```

Should be what you need, and it is simpler than joining tables.
Just dont forget to use the user as a parameter instead of using its id:

```
query.setParameter("user", user);
```

Comment: What would be the difference if we use `.. :user in elements(d.accessors)` instead of `... :user MEMBER OF(d.accessors)`?

Comment: @Manuel: [What's the difference between the IN and MEMBER OF jpql operators](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915822/whats-the-difference-between-the-in-and-member-of-jpql-operators)

Answer (score 26):

```
select distinct d from Document d inner join d.accessors a where a.id = :id
```

You should learn how SQL joins work, and then learn how to use joins in JPQL. That's essential. You'll find plenty of tutorials online. Google is your friend.

Comment: @user1071828 you are supposed to click the tick to indicate that it was the right answer ;-)

Comment: can you please check this question?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12051559/jpa-join-fetch-query-with-many-to-many

Comment: Please, do NOT forget the distinct. I couldn't figure out why I was ending up with duplicate entities :')