# How to remove Hibernate deprecation warning message

Tags: java, hibernate, warnings, deprecated

We have a query:

```
 List<Book> books = session.createQuery(
       "from Book b where :x member of b.bookCategories")
       .setParameter("x", crimeStory)
       .list();
```

But when executing this query, we got a warning message:

> WARN  10:19:41 deprecation: HHH90000016: Found use of deprecated
>   'collection     property' syntax in HQL/JPQL query [null.elements];
>   use collection function     syntax instead [elements(null)].

I tried to change the query to:

```
List<Book> books = session.createQuery(
    "from Book b where ? in elements(b.bookCategories)")
    .setParameter(0, crimeStory).list();
```

but the warning message was still there.

Please help me to fix this warning.

P/s: We are currently using Hibernate 5.0.2

Answer (score 15):

It is legal JPA and so should not be deprecated. See also http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2.0-fr-oth-JSpec/.

See https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10621 for the JIRA about this bug.

You could just hide the message by adding `log4j.logger.org.hibernate.orm.deprecation=error` to your `log4j.properties`.

(I know this was an old question but it is used in the JIRA call)

Comment: Just as an FYI, I found out that changing the JPQL to use an inner join results in a much more efficient query.

Answer (score 8):

Instead of using `MEMBER OF`, rather use an `INNER JOIN`. The JSQL should then be

`from Book b inner join b.bookCategories bc where bc.id = :categoryId`

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8340001/67796

Answer (score 8):

As a side note, to simply hide (not fix) messages like this, as of **2017** and **Log4j2**, use `org.hibernate.orm.deprecation`, for example:

```
<Logger name="org.hibernate.orm.deprecation" additivity="false" level="WARN">
    <RegexFilter regex=".*HHH90000016.*" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
    …
</Logger>
```

Be sure to use the specific code for your particular deprecation message, in this particular case it was `HHH90000016`, but for Criteria-API deprecation warnings it would be `HHH90000022`, and so on.

Or to disable **all** Hibernate deprecation messages (not recommended):

```
<Logger name="org.hibernate.orm.deprecation" additivity="false" level="ERROR">
    …
</Logger>
```