# Spring Data + Hibernate 5 (Spring Boot 1.4) - getting Deprecation Messages

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data

I recently migrated from Spring Boot 1.3.6 to 1.4.0. Now I get several warnings of the same kind in my logfile:

```
org.hibernate.orm.deprecation: HHH90000016: Found use of deprecated 'collection property' syntax in HQL/JPQL query [null.elements]; use collection function syntax instead [elements(null)].
```

The warnings are caused by my spring-data repositories. Some methods are using userdefined queries like

```
@Query("select ... where ... member of ...")
```

and others have queries derived by methode names like

```
List<...> findBy...Contains(...);
```

The question/answer [How to remove Hibernate deprecation warning message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33338186/how-to-remove-hibernate-deprecation-warning-message) shows how to prevent the message for userdefined queries. But it also states that its valid JPQL.
What is the recommended way handle this warning?

Answer (score 1):

It is a [bug in Hibernate](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11400) which has been fixed in 5.1.5 and 5.2.7.

You will need to update to Spring Boot 2.x. Even [Spring Boot 1.5.14](http://See%20https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.14.RELEASE/reference/html/appendix-dependency-versions.html) still has Hibernate 5.0.12. However, [Spring Boot 2.0.3](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/appendix-dependency-versions.html) has Hibernate 5.2.17.