# PA JPQL: check if all collection items don't have attribute with predefined value

Tags: java, sql, jpa, hql, jpql

I have the following class structure:

```
class TransactionRelation{
      Transaction req;
      Transaction resp;
      ....
}
```

---

```
class Transaction{
    Long id;
    private Set<TransactionStateHistory> transactionStateHistory;
    ...
}
```

---

```
public class TransactionStateHistory {
    private Long id;    
    private TransactionState transactionState;
}
```

I need to query transactions who is `req` from `TransactionRelation`,
each transaction from result should has `TransactionStateHistory`  with type `type1`

and corresponding response transaction should not have  TransactionStateHistory`with type`type2`

How does JPQL suggest to resolve the following task?

This topic goes around my topic but my a bit more complicated

[JPA JPQL: select items when attribute of item (list/set) contains another item](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12644648/2674303)

I need to write something like this:

```
SELECT d FROM Document AS d WHERE: user MEMBER OF d.accessors.attribute
```

Comment: I think you probably want an `EXIST` expression with a subquery. However, the description of your requirement is a little convoluted. Could you perhaps provide an example? Alternatively, you could provide an equivalent SQL query for translation