# Issue when trying to use the IN operator in a JPQL query

Tags: hibernate, spring-data, jpql

the following query :

```
SELECT P FROM Project P WHERE :currentUser IN(P.assignedUsers)
```

throws the following error :

> org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement: "....";
>   expected "NOT, EXISTS, INTERSECTS, SELECT, FROM";

Am i using the IN operator wrong, or am i supposed to do it differently.

Project.assignedUsers : is a list containing users (a OneToMany Relationship).
and the currentUser parameter is a valid user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use implicit joins for this purpose; you probably want to utilize the [`member of`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915822/whats-the-difference-between-the-in-and-member-of-jpql-operators) operator:

```
SELECT P FROM Project P WHERE :currentUser MEMBER OF P.assignedUsers
```