# JPQL many to many - in clause

Tags: spring, jpa, jpql

Can you please help me find out what is wrong with the following JPQL query. It should filter books by their genres.

Query has additional OR conditions which I have removed due to better readability (with or without the other conditions the error is the same).

```
@Query("SELECT b FROM Book b WHERE " + 
        "b in (select distinct b1 FROM Book b1 inner join b1.genres genre where genre in :genres)")
List<Book> searchBooks(@Param("genres") List<Genre> genres);
```

Following is the stacktrace:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: , near line 1, column 197 [select count(b) FROM *.domain.Book AS b WHERE b.id = (select distinct b1.id FROM *.domain.Book b1 inner join b1.genres genre where genre in :genres_0_, :genres_1_)]
```

Relation between Book and Genre classes is ManyToMany undirectional.

```
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "books_genres",
                 joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "BOOK_ID"),
                 inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "GENRE_ID"))
    private List<Genre> genres;
```

I have checked the subquery separately and it works:

```
@Query("select distinct b1 FROM Book b1 inner join b1.genres genre where genre in :genres")
    List<Book> searchBooksByGenre(@Param("genres") List<Genre> genres);
```

Is it possible at all to use the subquery in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I had further issues with memberOf, pertaining to data format, when passing a list of genres and check if they exist in book genre list, query would fail with a data format exception.

```
@Query("SELECT b FROM Book b WHERE " +
        ":genres MEMBER OF b.genres")
```

with `@Param("genres") List<Genre> genres`

would cause the following (1 and 4 are ids of the Genre objects in genres parameter passed to the query):

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Data conversion error converting "(1, 4)"; SQL statement:
```

I have abandoned the mentioned solution and managed to solve the issue using the "subquery" as a normal query and then continued adding conditions to the query.

So final solution is the following:

```
@Query("select distinct b1 FROM Book b1 inner join b1.genres genre where genre in :genres AND (---additional querys---)")
```

Comment: You may have been able to accomplish this by using a bunch of "AND EXISTS (subquery) AND EXISTS (subquery)" etc.

Answer (score 3):

Your query with nested select is OK, but you must use [MEMBER](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16764_01/apirefs.1111/e13046/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_collection_member) keyword instead of `IN` when you want to search in collection of entities.

Here is a good explanation of `MEMBER` and `IN`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9820394/784594. Also have a look at here: http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/collection#NOT_MEMBER_OF_

**However**, even if the documentation says that `IN` keyword is used when you compare according a list passed as a parameter, hibernate seems to behave oddly if you pass list of entities instead of list of primitive values. I came accross this recently and **using `MEMBER` fixed the problem**. I am not sure if this is a hibernate bug or whether all other providers behave the same way.

In the documentation to ObjectDB, you may read that it treats `IN` and `MEMBER` in the same way. In my opinion, there is no reason why there should be 2 keywords if JPA provider should have enough information to interpret the query even if `IN` was used in both cases.