# @Query giving QuerySyntaxException

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I want to get the rows from `Communication` table whose `appointment_type_ids` list contains `Integer`.

Communication.java

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "communication")
public class Communication{

    @Column("id")
    private Long id;

    @Column("name")
    private String name;

    @Column("appointment_type_ids")
    private List<Integer> appointmentTypeIds;

}
```

CommunicationRepository.java

```java
@Repository
public interface CommunicationRepository extends JpaRepository<Communication, Long>,
        QuerydslPredicateExecutor<Communication>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Communication> {

    @Query("SELECT c FROM communication c WHERE ?1 = ANY(c.appointment_type_ids)")
    List<Communication> findAppointments(Integer integer);
}
```

I am getting the following error

`org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: c near line 1, column 56 [SELECT c FROM communication c WHERE ?1 = ANY(c.appointment_type_ids)]`

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should refer to the table via `Communication` name not `communication`. So it should be

```sql
SELECT c FROM Communication c WHERE ?1 = ANY(c.appointment_type_ids)
```

Comment: Why, if the table name is `communication` ? Although I tried using `Communication`, still same exceptions.

Comment: @jennyjenkins its a JPA query not native one, you should address the entity class which is `Communication`. And `appointment_type_ids` should be `appointmentTypeIds`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But even `@Query("SELECT c FROM Communication c  WHERE ?1 = ANY(c.appointentTypeIds)")`  gives the same results. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

[ANY](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/java-ee-tutorial/jpa/jpql-all-any-expressions.html) expression needs a subquery, I think you need [MEMBER OF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9820394/3635454) for your query.

```
@Query("SELECT c FROM Communication c  WHERE ?1 MEMBER OF c.appointentTypeIds")
```

Comment: Thank you again! This compiles fine but I had to add `@ElementCollection` with the `appointmentTypeIds` field. And after that on trying to `PUT` values into table with `"appointment_type_ids":[3,8],` I get a response `{
    "code": "UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION",
    "message": "The provided 3 is not a List!"
}`

Comment: @jennyjenkins one step at a time. First of all does after modifying the `@Query`, `CommunicationRepository#findAppointments` work as per your intentions? If yes then your original question is answered, you should upvote/mark as correct the answer(s) that solved your problem. If you have another question like the `PUT` operation in your comment above then it is a completely different question and you should post a new question including all the necessary info for the community to help you out. thanks

Comment: I don't know if it did because I didn't have any idea how to deal with columns marked as `@ElementCollection` and so I couldn't actually test it. What however ended up working for me was `@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM communication c WHERE ?1 = ANY(c.appointment_type_ids)", nativeQuery = true)
 
List<Communication> findAppointments(Integer integer);`. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

can you try this :

```
SELECT c FROM Communication c WHERE ?1  in(c.appointment_type_ids)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Comment: Thank you for answering! Using this I get `ERROR: operator does not exist: integer = integer[]` when `findAppointments()` is called.

Comment: try to use native query if it work tell me 
@Query(value="SELECT c FROM Communication c WHERE ?1  in(c.appointment_type_ids)",nativeQuery = true)